# send an event function to a button from one class to other class

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling

I have a class (class1)
in this class i have a function and anther class:

```
class2 _class2 = new class2();    
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Now I have another class (class2)
that have a button in it
I want to send the button the function (Button_Click) so i can insert it to
the button event click
(button.click +=)

the class2 build multiple buttons in a loop for class1,
i want that when some one click one of the buttons it will go to the event function (Button_Click) in
class 1
I hope I was clear
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think I understand what you want but your sample is not clear (Class 1/2) please post a complete sample with both classes.

Comment: you can't send anything between classes they are static compile time things. Do you want tpo send it between objects? (The answer lies partly in the difference between classes and objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `protected void Button_Click` to `public void Button_Click`.
Then from somewhere else, go:

```
Button b; // defined in class2, for example

class1 _class1 = new class1();

b.Click += new EventHandler(_class1.Button_Click);
```

Comment: but how can i send the function (Button_Click) from class1 to class2 using the class2 constractor

Comment: Swap 1 with 2 in that example, I guess.

Comment: new EventHandler(...) is redundant you can simply so += _class1.Button_Click

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to "bubble" the event from for example one user control to a calling user control? If so, you need to to these things:

In the control where the button is clicked (a):
- Add the event handler to the button.Click

In the caller control (b)
- Subscribe to the event creating a function which is referenced in the markup: usercontrol(a) theeventhandlerina="the function in b"

Answer (score 0):

if class2 is within class one you could have an add function, something similare to

```
_class2 = new Class2();
_class2.AddButton("button1",ButtonClick);
_class2.AddButton("button2",ButtonClick);
_class2.AddButton("button3",ButtonClick);


//in class2
public void AddButton(string buttonName, EventHandler handler)
{
   var newButton = new Button(buttonName);
   newButton.click+= handler;

}
```

this is of course a contrived example but it should get the point across